# How to substract two calculated columns from two different lists in sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow

I have 2 lists. In list 1 i have calculated column 1 and in list 2 calculated colum 2. How can i substract calculated column 1 and calculated column 2 and update that result in some oder column?

Answer (score 1):

Use SharePoint Designer to create a Workflow which reads the values, does the calculation and writes the result.
If you don't know Designer start with the basics, see what actions Designer can do, play with it for a day. Then create your own workflow.